# What's the legendary drop rate of Ghom?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is it close to elites? Is it worth to do Ghom repetitively? And in that case, should I do it in adventure mode or normal mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people that I'v eseen run it does it in story mode as the waypoint is right next to him.  As for drop rate, he's considered a 'boss drop' which gives more loot than elites, thus more chances at legendary items.

Most people who does this run wears a [Mara's Kalideoscope](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/maras-kaleidoscope) which completely nullfies his poison damage.  I suppose the advantage is greater for HC players since there is zero chance of dying, even on T6 when wearing that amulet.

Whether its worth it or not is pretty subjective I'll leave that up to you to decide.

Comment: if Ghom have even higher drop chance than Elites, I feel it's really efficient to farm legendaries with Ghom rush then. Since it requires some extra time to find elites, and normally in T3 or lower, I can beat Ghom in same time as beat an elite . But that's just my opinion though, is there anything wrong?

Comment: @user3064115 except he has significantly more health than elites, so I don't know how you can beat him in the same time it takes to fight an elite. On T3 he should have ~700m hp (single player) compared to elites with 100m hp. Also, finding elites is really easy imo by doing rifts. The biggest advantage is still that you can completely nullify him with mara's kalideoscope so you have 0 chance of dying.

Comment: Also I find repeatedly doing runs like Ghom or chests or whatever to be extremely boring.

Comment: Where is your source for bosses giving better loot than elites?  Every time I slay a boss or unique I never get anything.  Elites and rares always give something though.

Comment: I also agree with your comment about that being boring.  That's basically pre RoS tactics there and those were no fun at all.  Rifts & bounties are the way to go for not getting bored or burnt out.

Comment: @Mkalafut I'm purely saying they drop more items per kill than compared to elites, which basically equates to more chances of them being legendary. I don't think the % of legendary drop is higher though. I don't know how you never get anything, everytime I kill an act boss for a bounty he drops about twice as many items than an elite kill.  For example, most elite groups only drop 1 rare but SK typically drops 2-3 rares.

Answer (score 0):

The legendary drop rate of Ghom is different depending on your difficulty level. Most people farm bosses in normal mode because of the checkpoint system. If you're looking for legendary items, you get a much higher increase while in a rift, so you might want to consider elite farming a rift instead.

I've included the % Bonus for difficulties below for you.

```
Normal: 100% Health, 100% Damage, 0% extra gold bonus, 0% extra XP bonus

Hard: 200% Health, 130% Damage, 75% extra gold bonus, 75% extra XP bonus

Expert: 320% Health, 189% Damage, 100% extra gold bonus, 100% extra XP bonus

Doubled bounty currency rewards for Expert and all higher levels.

Master: 512% Health, 273% Damage, 200% extra gold bonus, 200% extra XP bonus

Imperial gems may drop instead of Marquise on Master and all higher levels.

Torment I: 819% Health, 396% Damage, 300% extra gold bonus, 300% extra XP bonus

Torment+ enables class Set Items at lvl 60+, and at lvl 70+ possible Key and Organ drops, plus increasing bonuses to legendary drop rates and extra bonuses to legendary drop rates in Nephalem Rifts.

Patch 2.0.5 enabled Torment-only items to drop from horadric caches earned on T1+.

Torment II: 1311% Health, 575% Damage, 400% extra gold bonus, 400% extra XP bonus

Patch 2.0.5 added a legendary drop rate bonus for horadric caches earned on Torment 2 and higher.
Torment III: 2097% Health, 833% Damage, 550% extra gold bonus, 550% extra XP bonus

Torment IV: 3355% Health, 1208% Damage, 800% extra gold bonus, 800% extra XP bonus

Torment V: 5369% Health, 1752% Damage, 1150% extra gold bonus, 1150% extra XP bonus

Torment VI: 8590% Health, 2540% Damage, 1600% extra gold bonus, 1600% extra XP bonus
```